# Como fazer uma frase ser alterada entre determinados horários?

Tags: javascript

Estou aprendendo JS agora, achei esse código com um contador, mas queria que em horário específico ele mudasse a frase "Próximo Evento". Entre o horário de 21h até 23h gostaria que esse "Próximo Evento" fosse trocado por "Acontecendo agora" e depois das 23h que ele voltasse como "Próximo Evento".

```js
const countdown = () => {
    const countDate = new Date("Mar 13, 2022 21:00:00").getTime();
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const gap = countDate - now;

    const second = 1000;
    const minute = second * 60;
    const hour = minute * 60;
    const day = hour * 24;

    const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day);
    const textHour = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
    const textMinute = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
    const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

    document.querySelector(".day").innerText = textDay;
    document.querySelector(".hour").innerText = textHour;
    document.querySelector(".minute").innerText = textMinute;
    document.querySelector(".second").innerText = textSecond;
};
setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #EEE;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.coming-soon {
    width: 850px;
    height: auto
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.countdown {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    bottom: 0;
}

.countdown-container {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.counter {
    height: 70%;
    margin: 0;
}

.counter h3 {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0;
}

.text-counter {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #242a38;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#time {
    color: #242a38;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.next-event {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    color: #242a38;
}

#event-next {
    font-size: .80em;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#event-name {
    font-size: .80em;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coming-soon">
    <div class="countdown">
        <div class="next-event">
            <p id="event-next">PRÓXIMO EVENTO:</p>
            <p id="event-name">NOME EVENTO</p>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-container">
            <div class="counter container-day">
                <h3 class="text-counter" style="font-weight: 900;">D</h3>
                <h3 id="time" class="day">Time</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="counter container-hour">
                <h3 class="text-counter" style="font-weight: 900;">H</h3>
                <h3 id="time" class="hour">Time</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="counter container-minute">
                <h3 class="text-counter" style="font-weight: 900;">M</h3>
                <h3 id="time" class="minute">Time</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="counter container-second">
                <h3 class="text-counter" style="font-weight: 900;">S</h3>
                <h3 id="time" class="second">Time</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

É possível?

Answer (score -2):

É preciso verificar se o contador é menor que zero quando o evento estiver a acontecer. Adicionas a data do fim do evento e se a data do fim for menor que a data de agora volta-se a colocar o texto.

```
const countdown = () => {
    const countDate = new Date("Mar 13, 2022 21:00:00").getTime();
    const endDate = new Date("Mar 13, 2022 23:00:00").getTime();
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const gap = countDate - now;

    const second = 1000;
    const minute = second * 60;
    const hour = minute * 60;
    const day = hour * 24;

    const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day);
    const textHour = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
    const textMinute = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
    const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

    document.querySelector(".day").innerText = textDay;
    document.querySelector(".hour").innerText = textHour;
    document.querySelector(".minute").innerText = textMinute;
    document.querySelector(".second").innerText = textSecond;

    if (textSecond <= 0 && textMinute <= 0 && textHour <= 0 && textDay <= 0) {
        document.querySelector("#event-next").innerText = "ACONTECENDO AGORA:";
    }

    if (endDate < now) {
        document.querySelector("#event-next").innerText = "PRÓXIMO EVENTO:";
    }
};
setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```